# Transferring movieclips in a swf to another swf

Tags: c#, asp.net, actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently creating a flash animation where the swf will run when called by the Windows Application done in c#.

Lets have an example, WinA and WinB (Seperate windows application called to run the swf).
In WinA, if a movieclip were to leave the boundaries set, I would like it to appear on WinB and vice versa, currently after googling for awhile I can't seem to find any way to start and find proper references.

As a student, my tutor has told me to use the c# to manage the "transition" of the movieclip. 
I'm sorry if the description is vague, but I really do need help on a way to get started.

Comment: Tutor is the person who should lead the way to starting point - it's his job. Probably he knows how to do it. So why not asking him if you stuck?

Comment: We are not here to help to do your homework. Sorry. Please try to do this homework yourself and if you get stuck in your code, or errors you can't get around this is the place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html), check the official documentation to understand how to use and also see some examples.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an intermediate file like a xml file or a text file (we call it param) which will be read and written by both WinA and WinB.

in application WinA and WinB you need to have a function to change the value of the param to -2 -1 0 1 2

```
   2 -> indicates that object is going out from right side of WinB
   1 -> indicates that object is going out from left side of WinB
   0 -> indicates that object is stop
   -1 -> indicates that object is going out from left side of WinA
   -2 -> indicates that object is going out from right side of WinA
```

you need to read file and update it in small period of time by try and catch for example every 500 miliseconds

now you can write a function to change the direction of animation is running in swf file by using externalInterface method in c# and responding function in swf object which changes the direction of animation in flash.

Comment: Bad advice, this would be slow, CPU consuming and there are much better alternative anyway. LocalConnection would work but ExternalInterface would do the job too.